# vlookup using pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe:

```
df1.tail()
Out[13]: 
               Date  Ticker     P1      P2     cpn  Source      Time
3290644  2020-02-27   COLOM -0.159   0.068     100      G1  21:43:32
3290645  2020-02-27     MEX -0.136  0.0907     100      G1  21:43:32
3290646  2020-02-27  PANAMA -2.071  -1.791     100      G1  21:43:32
3290647  2020-02-27    PERU -1.977  -1.698     100      G1  21:43:32
3290652  2020-02-27  ARGENT   62.1    62.9     500      B1  21:45:55
```

which can have multiple rows corresponding to one Date and Ticker.

I have another dataframe which only has one entry for each Date and Ticker combination.

```
df2.tail()
Out[12]: 
              Date  p-cpn  Ticker
354072  2020-02-27    500  UKRAIN
354073  2020-02-27    100    UKIN
354074  2020-02-27    100  URUGAY
354075  2020-02-27    500    VENZ
354076  2020-02-27    100  VIETNM

df2[df2.Ticker.isin(df1.tail().Ticker)].tail()
Out[38]: 
              Date  p-cpn  Ticker
354002  2020-02-27    100   COLOM
354004  2020-02-27    100   CHILE
354045  2020-02-27    100     MEX
354053  2020-02-27    100    PERU
354056  2020-02-27    100  PANAMA
```

For each Date + Ticker key in df1, I want to basically do a vlookup for 'p-cpn' column from df2.

I tried this but failed (resulting NaNs)

```
df1.merge(df2, on = ['Ticker', 'Date'], how='left').tail()
Out[14]: 
               Date  Ticker     P1      P2     cpn  Source      Time  p-cpn
2333154  2020-02-27   COLOM -0.159   0.068     100      G1  21:43:32    NaN
2333155  2020-02-27     MEX -0.136  0.0907     100      G1  21:43:32    NaN
2333156  2020-02-27  PANAMA -2.071  -1.791     100      G1  21:43:32    NaN
2333157  2020-02-27    PERU -1.977  -1.698     100      G1  21:43:32    NaN
2333158  2020-02-27  ARGENT   62.1    62.9     500      B1  21:45:55    NaN
```

Then I tried this but it takes forever

```
def get_p_cpn(data):
    cpn =  df2[(df2.Ticker == data.Ticker.iloc[0]) & (df2.Date == data.Date.iloc[0])]['p-cpn']
    if len(cpn) == 0:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return cpn.iloc[0]
df1['p-cpn'] = df1.groupby(['Date', 'Ticker']).apply(lambda x: get_p_cpn(x))
```

as dataframes are big

```
df1.shape
Out[15]: (2333159, 7)

df2.shape
Out[16]: (354077, 3)
```

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: in the data you shared, there is no value in df1.Ticker that exists in df2.Ticker. if u can, share a data where there are some values in both dataframes. or run a test and see if there are values in df1.Ticker present in df2.Ticker

Comment: @sammywemmy edited

Comment: Your function working correct ? I think `df1['p-cpn'] = df1.groupby(['Date', 'Ticker']).apply(lambda x: get_p_cpn(x))` ? Because  test it and output is `Series` with `MultiIndex`, so I think `join` is necessary. Also tested with `merge` and left join and got same output. Is possible share more data for see how working `groupby` solution and fail `merge` solution?

Answer (score 0):

Tested and get same output for your function and `merge`:

```
def get_p_cpn(data):
    cpn =  df2[(df2.Ticker == data.Ticker.iloc[0]) & (df2.Date == data.Date.iloc[0])]['p-cpn']
    if len(cpn) == 0:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return cpn.iloc[0]
df1 = df1.join(df1.groupby(['Date', 'Ticker']).apply(lambda x: get_p_cpn(x)).rename('p-cpn'), on=['Date','Ticker'])
print (df1)
               Date  Ticker      P1       P2  cpn Source      Time  p-cpn
3290644  2020-02-27   COLOM  -0.159   0.0680  100     G1  21:43:32  100.0
3290645  2020-02-27     MEX  -0.136   0.0907  100     G1  21:43:32  100.0
3290646  2020-02-27  PANAMA  -2.071  -1.7910  100     G1  21:43:32  100.0
3290647  2020-02-27    PERU  -1.977  -1.6980  100     G1  21:43:32  100.0
3290652  2020-02-27  ARGENT  62.100  62.9000  500     B1  21:45:55    NaN

df1 = df1.merge(df2, on = ['Ticker', 'Date'], how='left')
print (df1)
         Date  Ticker      P1       P2  cpn Source      Time  p-cpn_x  p-cpn_y
0  2020-02-27   COLOM  -0.159   0.0680  100     G1  21:43:32    100.0    100.0
1  2020-02-27     MEX  -0.136   0.0907  100     G1  21:43:32    100.0    100.0
2  2020-02-27  PANAMA  -2.071  -1.7910  100     G1  21:43:32    100.0    100.0
3  2020-02-27    PERU  -1.977  -1.6980  100     G1  21:43:32    100.0    100.0
4  2020-02-27  ARGENT  62.100  62.9000  500     B1  21:45:55      NaN      NaN
```